# If we have the vocabulary {$+,<,1,2,3$}, what does "$4$" mean?

Tags: logic

I'm doing some logic exercises, a part of them is determining if a few formulas are sentences, satisfiable, tautologies and so on. We have that $\mathcal{V}$ is the vocabulary {$+,<,1,2,3$} with $+$ a binary function and $<$ a binary relation. One of the $\mathcal{V}$-formulas which I am considering is $\forall x \forall y ((x < 2) \rightarrow ((x + 3) = 4))$. I don't understand what the "$4$" really means, since it is not a part of $\mathcal{V}$. Me and a friend thought we could call this a variable, but we don't understand; if we say that the universe consists of the natural numbers, then "$4$" is no variable, but if we consider a different universe that doesn't include the number four, then it will indeed be a variable. Can someone clarify for me?

Comment: What is the actual question that you are being asked about the string of symbols including "4"? Based on the information you have given, that string is simply not a $\cal V$-formula. Was that the question?

Comment: Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the vocabulary {$+,<,1,2,3$} where $+$ is a binary function, $<$ is a binary relation and $1$, $2$ and $3$ are constants. Consider the following $\mathcal{V}$-formulas: [some other 9 simple formulas that I omit] 10. $\forall x \forall y ((x < 2) \rightarrow ((x + 3) = 4))$ a) Which of these 10 formulas are sentences b) Which of these 10 formulas are satisfiable? c) Which of these 10 formulas are tautologies?

Comment: @RobArthan I would appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not strictly a $\mathcal{V}$ formula as it uses a symbol not in your alphabet.  $4$ is a defined term and your formula is abbreviating a $\mathcal{V}$ formula that does not use $4$.  You might define $4=2+2$, then the formula you are considering expands to $\forall x \forall y ((x < 2) \rightarrow ((x + 3) = 2+2))$, which is in your language and can have its truth value evaluated.  Similarly, in set theory, $\subset$ is not a symbol of the language, but we know we can replace it with (a more complicated string) of symbols in the formal language.

Comment: This is my interpretation as well, but nevertheless the author Shawn Hedman considers this a $\mathcal{V}$-formula in his book "A First Course in Logic". Do you think there is any legitimate way to answer the questions (if it is a sentence, satisfiable formula or a tautology) or should I just consider the questions to be invalid?

Comment: In that case it is a sentence as it has no free variables.  Assuming the definition of $4$ and your axioms are in line with usual usage, the sentence is true, which can be shown by checking all the values for $x$ and stating that $y$ doesn't matter.

Comment: Just in case you are interested, it turns out that this was an error in the book (very annoying).